# How can I use my local variable as a global?

Tags: android, textview, global-variables

That's my code. In the onClick method I wanna refresh the textView. So every time I click the button, the method calls `int value = SecondFragment.getSmashValue();`. From there I get the value I set in another Fragment. I have to use this variable now in my TextView I set in my onCreate method. But it's always showing me the value 0! I think it's showing 0 because I try to make the variable global and the global value is 0.

So how can I make this variable global without losing its value?

```
import com.example.viewpagertest2.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tab1Activity extends Fragment {

Button b1;
static int theValue;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firsttabview, container, false);
    b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.refreshButton1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(handler);

    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.SP);
    tv.setText("" + theValue);

   b99.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            theValue = SecondFragment.getSmashValue();
            tv.setText("" + theValue);

        }
    });


    return rootView;


}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why r u declaring an local variable no need of it to get the value.Use global variable only.you can do this :

```
        if(b1==v){
          theValue = SecondFragment.getSmashValue(); //use theValue wherever u  wanted to use


    }
```

Comment: yeah you are right, but that's not the problem, I start to think there is a failure in my variable assigning

Comment: May be you are doing wrong is that ,after getting value in value you are again initialising it with the "theValue" variable.So it is taking "theValue" variable value.You do this :theValue=value;

Comment: yep that's true! @Seçkin said that also, I changed it to `theValue = ....` but it's still not working, maybe I have to overthink my variable assigning

Comment: May be it is not moving inside that click.You can try this : b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }
   }); in place of View.ClickListener

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the uninitialized `theValue` to your local `value` variable. Flip that statement over.

```
int value = SecondFragment.getSmashValue();
theValue = value;  // was value = theValue;
```

Also, make `tv` a field, so you can update your TextView from your event handler.

```
tv.setText("" + theValue);
```

Comment: the first thing was a really stupid mistake...
But what kind of field should I make?

Comment: Declare it as a field, out of your `onCreateView()`. So you can access it from other methods.

Comment: ah okey, I found the main problem, it's not the accesse, it's the TextView. It's not updated after the button click, I have to change the Tab so the old Tab is reloaded again...